# Same sku in different categories - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this head scratcher. I am trying to assign different categories to the same SKU in woocommerce.

You might be asking yourself, why does this idiot want do that?

There is a simple reason for that… I know that the categories one assigns to a product SKU determine the navigation to that SKU/Product.

The example that I will be using:

Lets pretend that the SKU is A95845 (*Red Ridding Hoods red juicy apple – included in the basket choices below*)

1. Baskets->Wooden->Varnished
2. Baskets->Wooden->Unvarnished
3. Baskets->Plastic->Red

I would like the user to get to the product A95845 for each instance. It is like Red Riding Hood taking alternate roads, but getting the happy ever after regardless of which road she chose. (*Well that is my opinion. And a way better interactive experience for the user.*)

Now for your opinions…

Comment: Just tick more than one category??

Answer (score 0):

You are hundred percent correct Steve. What I did wrong was the way I imported the categories. I used csv import and did not separate subcategories. This should have looked like this.

*Baskets->Wooden->Varnished*|*Baskets->Wooden->Unvarnished*|*Baskets->Plastic->Red*